# SQL Server DateTime Object and C# Datetime using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, datetime

I am pretty new to Entity Framework, I was able to create a process to add new entry to a database. However the last attribute in SQL Server is a `datetime` type. When I fill it using from the C# application it only includes the year month and day but not the time (cf the second entry below)

```
newEntry.TimeStamp = DateTime.Today;
```

(new entry is an instance of one of the class created by Entity Framework).

[image]

My initial idea was to change the format using :

```
string sqlFormatedDate = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

But obviously the application does not accept the type string when I get to the line :

```
newEntry.TimeStamp = sqlFormatedDate;
```

I get the error

> Cannot Implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.DateTime?'

How can one create a datetime object in C# that will properly be displayed in SQL Server?

**EDIT**:

Turns out one just has to use `Datetime.now`

Comment: what's wrong with `DateTime.Now` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.today(v=vs.110).aspx

```
Property Value
Type: System.DateTime
An object that is set to today's date, with the time component set to 00:00:00.
```

Use `DateTime.Now` instead which will return date with time part.

Comment: Will check your answer in 10 min, when stack let me

Answer (score 2):

`DateTime.Today` is only the Date portion of the DateTime, the time is set to midnight.
I think what you need is `DateTime.Now`.